# Julia Package for UI development

Tags: user-interface, julia

I want to develop a user interface written in Julia, with the following requirements:
Widgets: top menu, tabs, checkboxes, radio button, range sliders, text-fields
Widgets state: enabled/disabled, hidden/unhidden

I need your advice about the best Julia package to develop my GUI (preferable web-based but can also be desktop-based).

Thank you so much,
Sara

Comment: Hey Sara! Welcome, I suggest proposing this question on discourse.julialang.org as it is inherently an opinion based question and the Stack Overflow folks really enjoy closing opinion based questions! Looking forward to seeing you on Discourse!

Comment: Also, feel free to tag me on Discourse and I’ll post my suggestions there. My username here and there is the same.